# Touchpad not working on Ubuntu 18.04 and later versions

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, upgrade, touchpad

Recently when I was using my system with Ubuntu 18.04 version, my touchpad stopped working all of a sudden. Found that it was the issue in the OS installation. So I restored my system back to 16.04. And the touchpad was working. So I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 again. Now it has stopped working. Is there any way I can make touchpad work in Ubuntu 18.04 as well?

Comment: There is a bug in 4.15.0-72 kernel with Synaptics touchpads. So use the previous one or wait for a fix.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1854798  (which will impacted 18.04 using standard 4.15 kernel, or 16.04 using HWE kernel).  Refer aforementioned link which notes fix is currently in -proposed...  You can enable that, or use older kernel....

Comment: It did work! Thanks a lot! @Pilot6